# "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, application-loader

I tried to change something and build a new bundle. 
Now when I want to upload it using Application loader I get this error:

ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment' in 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/ExpoKitApp'.

Does anybody has a clue what could be the problem?
I'm using EXPO und react native.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am having the same problem.